# How can I make Vim open files in `--remote-silent` without getting an error when running just `vim`?

Tags: vim, bash

To open files in a pre-existing instance of Vim (MacVim in my case), I took [Derek Wyatt's advice](http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/vim-tutorial-videos/vim-intermediate-tutorial-videos/#onevim) and added this to my bash_profile:

```
alias mvim='mvim --remote-silent'
```

This works as long as I pass mvim an argument (`mvim myFile`, `mvim .`, etc.), but if I run `mvim` by itself, I get an error: `Argument missing after: "--remote-silent"`

So I replaced the above alias with the following function:

```
function mvim() {
  if [ $# > 0 ] ; then
    command mvim --remote-silent "$@"
  else
    command mvim
  fi
}
```

Now if I run `mvim` without an argument, I get the same error **and** a file named `0` gets written to the current directory. Things are still fine if I pass mvim arguments.

What am I missing here, and what's the best way to handle this?

*Thanks Ingo Karkat for clarifying. If anyone's interested, here's how I'm handling this now:*

```
function ivim {
  if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
    command mvim --remote-silent "$@"
  elif [ -n "$( mvim --serverlist )" ] ; then
    command mvim --remote-send ":call foreground()<CR>:enew<CR>:<BS>"
  else
    command mvim
  fi
}
```

The `:<BS>` at the end of the `elif` branch is just to clear the command line. It feels a little hacky, but I don't know how else to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bash, this *test* expression isn't correct: `[ $# > 0 ]`; you're redirecting stdout (`>`) to the `0` file. Instead, either use the old-style `-gt` "greater than" operator

```
[ $# -gt 0 ]
```

or the newer `[[` built-in conditional command:

```
[[ $# > 0 ]]
```

Comment: `[[ $# > 0 ]]` is not an arithmetic ‘greater than’. You probably meant `(( $# > 0 ))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to name the function `mvim` instead of something else (because you've become used to type `mvim` or whatever other reasons), here's a simple fix.

```
function mvim {
  if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
    command mvim --remote-silent "$@"
  elif [ -n "$( command mvim --serverlist )" ] ; then
    command mvim --remote-send ":call foreground()<CR>:enew<CR>:<BS>"
  else
    command mvim
  fi
}
```

Note the added `command` before calling `mvim` in the `elif`.